# File descriptor and exec

Tags: c, pipe, fork, fifo, named

I have one parent process and I created with fork 2 children like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // loop will run n times (n=2)
{
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        execl("merge","merge",fifo1[i],fifo2[i],"2",NULL);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The fifos are named pipes.I call execl and on the merge executable I open the named pipes like this.

```
if ((readfd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY )) < 0) {
    perror("server: can't open read fifo");
}
server(readfd);
```

I also write something from the parent to the children like this. (I have opened the fds previosly, but I didnt write it here).

```
for (int = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    n = strlen(word);
    if (write(fd_write[i], word, n) != n) {
        perror("client: filename write error");
    }
}
```

I want to write something on the one child and something else on the other, but both the two children have the same file descriptor(read) 4, and it's like I write on the same named pipe. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't matter if both children use the same integer value for the file descriptor.  If you `open`ed the file descriptor pre-fork and let the child inherit it, then each would share the same file description which would be problematic.  But since you `open` after the fork, the file description in each child is completely different.

Comment: Note that `perror()` only prints a message — it doesn't exit.  That means that your code `if ((readfd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY )) < 0) { perror("server: can't open read fifo"); } server(readfd);` will try to use the "known to be bad" file descriptor after all.  Look at the functions in `<err.h>` (or a package such as my `stderr.[ch]` files — available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory).